# How to tackle a column with parenthesis for snowflake connector pd_writer

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am writing a dataframe to Snowflake table via `snowflake-connector`. The column in the `df` has `(`, `)` in it. I am trying to write with `df.to_sql(table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', method=pd_writer)`.

1. Which is creating the table on the fly.
2. Converts the `df` in parquet file and `PUT` into S3 bucket.
3. Tries to `COPY` the parquet data to `table` but getting the exception.

COPY sql -

```
COPY INTO "DB1.SCHM1.T1" /* Python:snowflake.connector.pandas_tools.write_pandas() */
("Name", "Year(1)", "Year(2)") 
FROM 
(SELECT $1:Name, $1:Year(1), $1:Year(2) FROM @"djaks") 
FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=PARQUET COMPRESSION=auto) 
PURGE=TRUE ON_ERROR=abort_statement
```

Error -

```
SQL Compilation error: Syntax error line 1 at position X unexpected '1'. syntax error line 1 at position X ','.
```

Which is coming because of the syntax `$1:Year(1)`. I can't change the column name, what are the other solution(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the column identifier in quotes:
(SELECT $1:"Name", $1:"Year(1)", $1:"Year(2)" FROM @"djaks")

Unquoted identifiers cannot have ( or ) in snowflake.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html

Comment: The `COPY` sql query is system-generated once I invoke `pd_writer`